# Grep in bash issues

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

Sample string:

```
--000000000000f104a6057d4a0a10
```

Here I need to get for sure: "`--`"

Same files also contain a lot of similar strings; `------=_`, `--=_` , `-----------`, `--<` which currently also get returned. Therefore the regex must be fit. Currently I also get them :(

Regex I have: `^--\w+` fails in grep, expected results as above, but works in Gedit, Bluefish... grep: `grep -r '^--\w+' file` .. and returns me no result, and `grep -r '^--' file` to many of the wrong.

Another one, similar, but more complex:
Sample string:

```
--b1_3445ee3d64c0259d451a115045580266
```

identify this part: `--b1_....`

Answer (score 5):

Standard `grep` does not by default understand Perl-like regular expressions (PCRE) such as `\w`.  GNU `grep` does handle `\w` (and `\W`) even in basic and extended regular expressions, which is an extension to the standard behaviour. Other PCRE is enabled in GNU `grep` using its `-P` option.

The reason your command returns nothing is that `+` is an extended regular expression operator, which needs `-E` to work in GNU `grep`:

```
grep -E '^--\w+' file
```

Without `-E`, your expression tries to match `--W+` literally (where `W` is some single character matched by `\w`).

Also note that you may want to anchor the expression at the end as well, as in

```
grep -E '^--\w+$' file
```

or else you'll match lines containing non-`\w` characters later, like

```
--00000000=
```

Alternatively, you may use

```
grep -xE -e '--\w+' file
```

which does the same thing.  The `-x` option forces a full line match.  The `-e` is needed to delimit the expression from the command line options as the pattern starts with a dash.

GNU `grep` also understands `\+` in basic regular expressions (i.e. when using `grep` without `-E` or `-P`):

```
grep -x -e '--\w\+' file
```

Or you could use `\{1,\}` in place of the `\+`.

---

With a non-GNU `grep` (*and* GNU `grep`), you may use `[[:alnum:]_]` (which matches a letter or a digit, or an underscore which is included separately here) in place of `\w`:

```
grep -xE -e '--[[:alnum:]_]+' file
```

To match hexadecimal numbers and underscores, use `[[:xdigit:]_]`:

```
grep -xE -e '--[[:xdigit:]_]+' file
```

or,

```
LC_ALL=C grep -xE -e '--[0-9a-fA-F_]+' file
```

The setting of `LC_ALL` to `C` (or to `POSIX`) for the `grep` command is necessary since character ranges are locale dependent.

Comment: See also `grep '^--[[:alnum:]_]'`. The `+` is redundant unless you add something to match after that sequence of `\w`s (like a `$` anchor) or use GNU `grep`'s `-o` (to print what is matched as opposed to the line  with the match).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think the intention is to anchor the expression at the end of the input string. I will edit and do this earlier than I do now.

Answer (score 0):

- Use extended regexp

```
grep -E '^--\w+'
egrep '^--\w+'
```

- or escape the repetition-operator

```
grep '^--\w\+'
```

Comment: Note that `\w` is a PCRE, which is probably the same as `[[:alnum:]_]` in an extended regular expression. You enable PCRE in GNU `grep` with `-P`.

Comment: This takes me a lot further ;)

Comment: @Kusalananda According to re_format(7) extended REs understand those shortcuts too. grep (GNU grep) 2.25 works with \w without need to enable PCRE or extended REs.

Comment: @JakubJindra Yes, it appears GNU `grep` enables `\w` as an alias for `[_[:alnum:]]`. That and `\W` are the only PCRE it enables by default.